# How to move page mail title after category description in magento 2.3.1

Tags: category, frontend, magento2.3.1

- app/design/frontend/vendorname/modulename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

  ```
  <move element="page.main.title" destination="main.category.col.1" after="category.description"/>
  ```

[image]

So how to category name after category description move in magento 2.3

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/vendorname/modulename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
    <move element="category.description" destination="main.category.col.1" before="page.main.title"/>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="main.category.col.1" after="category.description"/>
```